# how to skip .htaccess rule in href=""

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing an application with php mvc and I was unable to use href since .htaccess adds the default "localhost/sitename/". I want to point to the external site but html href="#" ends up being "localhost/sitename/#".

How do i fix this?

1) .htaccess inside root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

2) .htaccess inside public folder:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitename/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: _“How do i fix this?”_ - by fixing what you put into the href attribute of the link to begin with. This has nothing whatsoever to do with URL rewriting. _“since .htaccess adds the default "localhost/sitename/"”_ - that is not the .htaccess doing anything, that is simply how resolving relative URLs to absolute ones on the _client side_ works.

Comment: `href="#"` does not point to an external site though.

Comment: Also the first code will create a rewrite loop...